# wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login redirect to current page

Tags: oracle, authentication, redirect, oracle-apex

I am building an apex app and using the `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login()` function . My current app's main page is page 102.

What I am trying to do is have a process run before the header that will validate the user and call the `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login()` method and redirect the user to the current page. Basically what I am going to do down the line is redirect to an error page if the user is not found but anyway my question is, I keep getting a redirect error when I redirect to the page that I am currently on. Is this not allowed? My function looks like this

```
wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login(P_UNAME       => :P102_USERNAME,
                              P_PASSWORD    => :P102_PASSWORD,
                              P_SESSION_ID  => v('APP_SESSION'),
                              P_FLOW_PAGE   => :APP_ID||':102');
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach would be to create an Authentication Scheme. This can be done in `Shared Components  -> Authentication Schemes`.

The `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login` procedure is already called after submit on the default login page so there's probably no need for you to call it.